# How can I make a Bootstrap div to cover multiple rows?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following grid with Bootstrap.
i would like to know if it is possible in first place to create this type of grid.
[image]

doing horizontal divs such as 1,2 ,4, 5 ,7 is udnerstandable, but what about div 3&6 that cover multiple rows.

i used:

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">4</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">5</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-8">6</div>
```

to create 4 5 6 part but what i get looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Bootstrap grid works on basis of flexbox. `Flexbox` major downside vs `CSS-Grid` is that it only is able to control 1 direction nto both directions. So you will require extra containers or solve it with a custom CSS-Grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very rough idea of how you might do it:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-9 row">
       <div class="col-6 box">1</div>
       <div class="col-6 box">2</div>
       <div class="col-4 row">
         <div class="col-12 box">4</div>
         <div class="col-12 box">5</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-8 row">
         <div class="col-12 box">6</div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-12 box">7</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-3 row">
       <div class="box">3</div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

You basically have to just draw rectangles around your groups and that is how they end up being ordered. e.g. first you draw a rectangle around `everything but 3` and `3`, those are your first columns. Then rectangle around `1 and 2` then `4, 5 and 6` and finally `7` etc.

Comment: could you tell me how can i keep padding:2px between every div a

Answer (score 0):

This is the grid structure you are trying to achieve. You can add style to this to achieve the exact output.

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-6">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="col-sm-12">4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">5</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="col-sm-12">6</div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        7
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3">
    3
</div>
```